# Summary Link Web Part and absolute URL

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I'm trying to create a link in a "Link Summary Web Part" that points to a different hostname of the same web application which uses different authentication.

Unfortunately, the absolute link is being truncated to a relative link due to the alternate access mapping.

Is there a way to trick this web part to store my absolute URL?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to do this that I have discovered. You have to create a separate list or roll your own web part, which is what we have done